# Using polymer project on WAMP

Tags: polymer, wamp

I'm currently starting to work on the project using polymer.
I'm able to set up and view the page using the polymer elements after setting up HTTP server using python -m SimpleHTTP server.

However when i tried to run it in WAMP, copying the project folder to root destination (www). I couldn't view the page properly & it is blank. May i know if i need to set up anything else to have it work on WAMP as well.

Comment: check the console, any errors there?

Comment: getting lists of failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

Comment: Not able to load the resource that i place in html import when i run it with WAMP
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(not found)  http://localhost:8080/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(not found)  http://localhost:8080/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/polymer/polymer.html
http://localhost:8080/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html
http://localhost:8080/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html

Comment: so, import path is wrong, fix that.